# How to fix ImportError: No module named selenium on Mac

Tags: python, selenium, import

**Python version 2 OSX**

I know that there were other questions like this asked on other posts

but they all said to run `pip install selenium` which I did and even then I cannot seem to be able to import selenium

When I do `pip freeze`

It prints `selenium==3.141.0` which means that it is on there but I cannot seem to be able to get selenium imported onto *Pycharm*

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do this, in your code write `from selenium import *`, it should get underlined(red line), then click on `selenium` where you have imported it, a red bulb would appear, click on that and install selenium from there

Comment: @ThatBird when i click on the bulb the only options were rename reference and convert to import selenium. Should i do import?

Comment: @ThatBird actually on a different python file i did what you said and i got "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 192, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
    return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'"

Comment: is the import working when you are not using pycharm

Comment: Try upgrading your pip. Then try first step again

Comment: @Jeril kinda when i import on terminal it works but not on anaconda

Comment: @ThatBird when i updated to the latest pycharm and also latest PIP it still doesnt work. any suggestsion?

Comment: are you using Pycharm or anaconda

Comment: PyCharm isn't using the same Python interpreter you installed selenium with